# Missing table template on back and forth navigation

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to build an application that has table#1 with clickable items and display data in another view with table#2 depending on which item you clicked in the first table.

This is some weird behaviour and I'll try to explain the problem the best I can:

The application works fine the first time you use it - I click an Item in table#1 -> it navigates to the view with table#2 and displays the dependent data. Everything works perfectly fine.

Now if i navigate back to table#1 and click another item, it loads table#2 but without any data.

The third time (and every time after that) I navigate back and click an item in table #1 and table#2 is supposed to load I get the error message :

> "Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element sap.m.Table"

I have tried reloading the item aggregation, destroying the template on navigation, reloading model data and setting the templateSharable flag to true / false but nothing helped in any way.

I'm posting the relevant code for the view with table #2 below

My XML Code:

```
<f:SimpleForm id="simpleform" editable="true" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
    <f:content>
        <semantic:SemanticPage id="page" headerPinnable="false" toggleHeaderOnTitleClick="false" >
            <semantic:content id="posContent">
                <Table 
                id="rkDetailTable"
                noDataText="{i18n>tableNoDataText}"
                >
                    <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Pos ID"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="{i18n>Art_RkDetail}" />
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="{i18n>Betrag_RkDetail}"/>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem id="rkDetailTableTemplate" type="Navigation" press="onDetail">
                            <cells>
                                <ObjectIdentifier title="{RkposId}" />
                                <Text text="{RksatzId}" />
                                <ObjectNumber number="{RkposBetrag}" unit="EUR" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>
            </semantic:content>
        </semantic:SemanticPage>
    </f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

The corresponding controller:

```
onInit: function () {   
    this.getRouter().getRoute("RkItemDetail").attachMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);
},
onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
    var oArguments = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
    var RkId = oArguments.RkId;


    var sBindingPathAbrechnung = "/AbrechnungSet(" + RkId + (")");
    this.getView().byId("simpleform").bindElement(sBindingPathAbrechnung); 


    var sBindingPathPosition = "/AbrechnungSet(" + RkId + (")/ToPos");
    this.byId("rkDetailTable").bindItems({
        path: sBindingPathPosition,
        template: this.byId("rkDetailTableTemplate"),
        templateShareable: true
    });
}
```

Disregard the element binding, it is used for something else in that view.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you table change the `<items>` aggregation to `<dependents>`.

```
<Table 
    id="rkDetailTable"
    noDataText="{i18n>tableNoDataText}"
>
    <columns>
        ...
    </columns>
    <dependents>
        <ColumnListItem id="rkDetailTableTemplate" type="Navigation" press="onDetail">
            ...
        </ColumnListItem>
    </dependents>
</Table>
```

Comment: that was the solution thank you very much!

do you have a suggestion how I could have found that out on my own? I wasted so much time trying to solve this problem

Comment: I had the same problem and it took me some time to figure it out as well :) I found this 'trick' to declare the template in xml somewhere in a blogpost on the SAP forums. With `<items>` it is not working because it is supposed to be used to create a hardcoded list of items. In your case it was working the first time because the framework got the item on your first visit, removed it because new items got bound (.bindItems() ) and on the second visit, the item is no longer present. I hope you understand what I mean, I'm not the best explainer ^^